# Sum from each 0 position in a 0 1 vector in R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the sum of all 1s after each 0 in a vector of 0s and 1s.

E.g.,

0 0 1 0 1 
would be:
2 (all 1s after 1st 0) + 2 (all 1s after 2nd zero) + 1 (one 1 after 3rd zero on the 4th position) = 5

So not 6 what would be the case if you just sum the whole vector for each 0 in the vector (3*2).

This is what I have tried but does not work:

```
a <- rbinom(10, 1, 0.5)
counter <- 0
for (i in a){
  if(i == 0)
  counter <- counter + sum(a[i:10])
}
print(counter)
```

I first create a vector of 10 random 0s and 1s. I make a counter which starts at 0, then I try to calculate the sum from each i position until the final position (10th), but only when i equals 0.

What it actually does is just calculate the sum of all 1s for each 0 in the vector.

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Expected output looks like? Use set.seed() before generating random numbers so result will be reproducible.

Comment: If you want a loop I would do `counter <- 0 ; for(i in which(x == 0)) counter <- counter + sum(tail(x, -i)) `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given

```
x <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

Here is a vectorized way

```
sum(rev(cumsum(rev(x))) * !x)
#[1] 5
```

Or using this input

```
set.seed(1)
a <- rbinom(10, 1, 0.5)
a
# [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

The result is

```
sum(rev(cumsum(rev(a))) * !a)
# [1] 16
```

---

**step by step**

When we calculate the reversed cumulative sum of `rev(x)` we get

```
rev(cumsum(rev(x)))
# [1] 2 2 2 1 1
```

The result shows us for each element in `x` how many `1`s there are until the end of the vector.

The idea to multiply this vector by `!x` is that we later only want to sum those elements for which `x` is zero, i.e. not 1 (or not `TRUE`).

Result

```
rev(cumsum(rev(x))) * !x
# [1] 2 2 0 1 0
```

This needs to be summed up to get desired output.

Comment: That's a nice one. Wouldn't think of it. Perhaps it makes sense to explain the logic

Comment: Thanks, this is actually more efficient, but difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a <- rbinom(10, 1, 0.5)
counter <- 0
for (i in seq_along(a)){
  if(a[i] == 0)
  counter <- counter + sum(a[i:10])
}
print(counter)
```

In yours example `i` is not an iterator. It's a value of `a` vector. So `a[i:10]` gives either `a[0:10]` or `a[1:10]`.

Comment: Thanks this works! I need to get my head arond what i actually is doing and how it is working in a loop (just started with learning R).

Comment: Good attitude :) Way better than copying and pasting someone's code without understanding it.

Comment: There is no need to loop over the whole vector. looping over zeros is enough.